# ‘MPI_GET’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, mpi

I am using RMA for the first time, and I was search through the internet and I could not find the answer for declaring the MPI_PUT and MPI_GET and other flags related to the RMA

I am declaring the MPI.h at the start of the file:

```
#include <mpi.h>
```

but I am getting the following errors for my RMA dependencies:

```
 error: ‘MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘MPI_GET’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘MPI_PUT’ was not declared in this scope
```

but for creating the window I am not getting the same errors and declaring the mpi.h is enough for that.

Comment: In `C`, you should use `MPI_Get()` and `MPI_Put()` (case sensitive)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet but how about error: ‘MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE’ was not declared in this scope errors?

Comment: simply fix the typo.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I fixed it for put and get, but the flags MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE are for fences MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOPUT | MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE, win);

Comment: fix the remaining typo

Comment: It's not `MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE`. Check the spelling with the documentation.

Comment: Fun fact, google returns zero result for `MPI_MODE_NOPROCEDE`!